# Pandas Melt several groups of columns into multiple target columns by name

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I would like to melt several groups of columns of a dataframe into multiple target columns. Similar to questions [Python Pandas Melt Groups of Initial Columns Into Multiple Target Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187963/python-pandas-melt-groups-of-initial-columns-into-multiple-target-columns) and [pandas dataframe reshaping/stacking of multiple value variables into seperate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105368/pandas-dataframe-reshaping-stacking-of-multiple-value-variables-into-seperate-co). However I need to do this explicitly by column name, rather than by index location.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('a','b','c',1,2,3,'aa','bb','cc'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 4, 5, 6, 'dd', 'ee', 'ff')],
                  columns=['a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3','b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3','c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3'])
df
```

Original Dataframe:

```
    id   a_1  a_2  a_3  b_1  b_2  b_3  c_1  c_2  c_3
0   101   a    b    c    1    2    3    aa   bb   cc
1   102   d    e    f    4    5    6    dd   ee   ff
```

Target Dataframe

```
     id   a   b   c
0   101   a   1   aa
1   101   b   2   bb
2   101   c   3   cc
3   102   d   4   dd
4   102   e   5   ee
5   102   f   6   ff
```

Advice is much appreciated on an approach to this.

Comment: There is a more intuitive solution that uses `pd.wide_to_long` function which is built exactly for this situation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a more efficient way to do these type of problems that involve melting multiple different sets of columns. The [pandas function wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is built for these exact situations.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['a', 'b', 'c'], i='id', j='dropme', sep='_')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('dropme', axis=1)\
  .sort_values('id')

    id  a  b   c
0  101  a  1  aa
2  101  b  2  bb
4  101  c  3  cc
1  102  d  4  dd
3  102  e  5  ee
5  102  f  6  ff
```

Comment: A small note: this answer works like a charm, but you have to include (manually) the 'id' column and its values into the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert the column names to multi index based on the columns pattern and then stack at a particular level depending on the result you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(df.columns.str.split("_")))
df.stack(level = 1).reset_index(level = 1, drop = True).reset_index()

# id    a   b    c      
#101    a   1   aa
#101    b   2   bb
#101    c   3   cc
#102    d   4   dd
#102    e   5   ee
#102    f   6   ff
```

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` also works

Answer (score 3):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['id'])

pd.lreshape(df, cols.groupby(cols.str.split('_').str[0])).sort_values('id')
Out: 
    id  a   c  b
0  101  a  aa  1
2  101  b  bb  2
4  101  c  cc  3
1  102  d  dd  4
3  102  e  ee  5
5  102  f  ff  6
```

Comment: You explain why this " cols.groupby(cols.str.split('_').str[0]) " returns a dict?

Comment: [Index.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.groupby.html)  returns a dict. Probably because doing arithmetic on the index is not a common use case and generally we need the groups instead.

Comment: It was unexpected behavior, thats why I ask.

Answer (score 1):

One option is [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which abstracts the process, and is efficient:

```py
# pip install janitor
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern = '([a-z]+)_*')

   a  b   c
0  a  1  aa
1  d  4  dd
2  b  2  bb
3  e  5  ee
4  c  3  cc
5  f  6  ff
```

The idea for this particular reshape is that whatever group in the regular expression is paired with the `.value` stays as the column header.