# pandas stack multiple columns into multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 6k columns wide, of the format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('jan 1 2000','a','b','c',1,2,3,'aa','bb','cc'), ('jan 2 2000','d', 'e', 'f', 4, 5, 6, 'dd', 'ee', 'ff')],
                  columns=['date','a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3','b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3','c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3'])

df
    date         a_1  a_2  a_3  b_1  b_2  b_3  c_1  c_2  c_3
0   jan 1 2000   a    b    c    1    2    3    aa   bb   cc
1   jan 2 2000   d    e    f    4    5    6    dd   ee   ff
```

I want:

[image]

I have looked at:
[Pandas Melt several groups of columns into multiple target columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862832/pandas-melt-several-groups-of-columns-into-multiple-target-columns-by-name) and [Pandas: Multiple columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column) but am unable to form a correct solution.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` in columns with `split` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('date', 'ID')).reset_index()

print (df)
        date ID   1   2   3
0 2000-01-01  a   a   b   c
1 2000-01-01  b   1   2   3
2 2000-01-01  c  aa  bb  cc
3 2000-01-02  a   d   e   f
4 2000-01-02  b   4   5   6
5 2000-01-02  c  dd  ee  ff
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `pd.wide_to_long` and some dataframe reshaping.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['a','b','c'], 'date', 'ID', '_')\
  .rename_axis('ID', axis=1)\
  .stack()\
  .unstack(1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
ID         date ID   1   2   3
0   jan 1, 2000  a   a   b   c
1   jan 1, 2000  b   1   2   3
2   jan 1, 2000  c  aa  bb  cc
3   jan 2, 2000  a   d   e   f
4   jan 2, 2000  b   4   5   6
5   jan 2, 2000  c  dd  ee  ff
```

Where df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('jan 1, 2000','a','b','c',1,2,3,'aa','bb','cc'), ('jan 2, 2000','d', 'e', 'f', 4, 5, 6, 'dd', 'ee', 'ff')],
                  columns=['date','a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3','b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3','c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3'])
df
```

Input df:

```
          date a_1 a_2 a_3  b_1  b_2  b_3 c_1 c_2 c_3
0  jan 1, 2000   a   b   c    1    2    3  aa  bb  cc
1  jan 2, 2000   d   e   f    4    5    6  dd  ee  ff
```

Comment: In this case, wide_to_long is more convenient compared with stack/melt

Comment: I received error: ValueError: Duplicated level name: "ID", assigned to level 2, is already used for level 1.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

df.pivot_longer(
    index = 'date', 
    names_to = ('ID', '.value'), 
    names_sep='_', 
    sort_by_appearance=True)

         date ID   1   2   3
0  jan 1 2000  a   a   b   c
1  jan 1 2000  b   1   2   3
2  jan 1 2000  c  aa  bb  cc
3  jan 2 2000  a   d   e   f
4  jan 2 2000  b   4   5   6
5  jan 2 2000  c  dd  ee  ff
```